# IHostedService app not starting automatically on azure app service

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-app-service-plans, ihostedservice

I have an IHostedService app in dotnet core 3.1, which is deployed on azure app service plan, but it needs to browse the app service to activate IHostedService.

I have automatic deploy pipeline , when it deploy the IHostedService app,it stopped working and I have to start manually by clicking browse button.

Anyone know how to activate IHostedService after deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleague who is devops expert find the solution for me.

App service -> configuration -> general settings -> Always On [on]

The Always On feature keeps your Azure web applications up and running,